# Получить массив элементов на форме

Tags: c#, winforms

Как найти все label(к примеру) на форме ?

Comment: Вот [ответ](http://hashcode.ru/questions/185180/c-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80-picturebox?%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0=1&focusedAnswerId=185210#185210) на аналогичный вопрос. Вкратце: вы не должны этого хотеть.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach (var ctrl in form.Controls)
{
    if (ctrl is Label)
    {
        // do something...
    }        
}
```

Comment: а ну такой вариант я знаю, я так понимаю он единственный?

Comment: Имхо, если предполагается дальнейшее использование `ctrl`, то лучше:

    Label label = ctrl as Label;
    if (label != null)
    {
        // Do something with label
    }

Comment: @eigenein, надеюсь, с этим ТС уже разберется самостоятельно :)
@cyber_ua, мало ли как еще можно извратиться. Этот вариант наиболее простой и очевидный.

Comment: @Flammable, понятно, спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Чуть более современный вариант:

```
foreach (var label in Controls.OfType<Label>())
{

}
```